# Timevis timeline on shinyapp with daterangeinput and select input

Tags: r, shiny

When trying to run the shiny app so that the timeline with my data displays and the date range input and select input works, only the date range input and select input displays.

```
library(shiny)
library(timevis)

data1=data.frame(id=1:49,
            group=B_no,
            content = Alcohol,
            start = Start_Date,
            end= End_Date,
            type='point')
data2=data.frame(id=unique(B_no),content=unique(B_no),title="B_no")

ui <- bootstrapPage(
 timevisOutput("timeline"),
 dateRangeInput("daterange1","Date range", 
             start = Start_Date, end = End_Date,
             min = "01-01-2013", max = "31-12-2016",
             format="dd/mm/yy",
             separator="-"),
 selectInput("BID","BID:",B_no)
  )

 server <- function(input, output, session) {
output$timeline <- renderTimevis({
timevis(data1,data2)
})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: your code does not work. I get errors. For example, `Error in unique(B_no) : object 'B_no' not found`

Comment: This is my data